# What would be the dynamics of a double-planet system, similar to Earth / Moon, but with both bodies nearly Earth-sized?

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, tidal-effect

Researching a sci-fi story involving a "twin-planet" system. Is such an arrangement (however unlikely) physically possible? And if so, must they be tidally locked with each other, similar to the Moon, month-long days, etc?  (or good reference sources for a layman?)

Comment: The Pluto-Charon system is more or less like this.

Comment: Though, of course, Pluto and Charon are not planets of the solar system (Pluto is a [dwarf planets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_planet) and Charon its moon).

Comment: Cross-posted on [Astronomy](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/7718/what-would-be-the-dynamics-of-a-double-planet-system-similar-to-earth-moon-b). My answer here obviously can be improved, but I think the OP should simply have waited for better answers here (which will come, I think).

Comment: The answer was very helpful so far and I regret that I'm too new to give it an upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why it should be impossible. A [binary planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_planet) system should exist in a reasonably stable orbital configuration.

As Javier pointed out, [Pluto and Charon](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/profile.cfm?Object=Pluto&Display=Sats) are similar in size and mass, like a small-scale version of what you describe. The important thing to note here is that the [barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#Astronomy) of the Pluto-Charon system is [*outside*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#Charon) either planet. In most systems (e.g. Earth-Sun, Jupiter-moons of Jupiter, etc.), the barycenter is inside one of the bodies (generally the more massive one). In the system you describe, the barycenter would be exactly in the middle of the system.

Pluto and Charon show that it is possible for two small bodies to exist in this arrangement. Certain [binary star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star) systems show the same characteristics: the barycenter is outside both bodies. This can thus happen on small and large scales; it seems likely it could happen somewhere in between.

I should add that I'm not quite sure how something like this could form. The bodies would have to form in just the right places, at just the right times.